# Why we need Preferences in android?

Tags: android, android-preferences

1. Can you explain me the logic behind
   Why we use preferences in android?

   1. How we can declare it in our
      application?
   2. What are the benefit to use it?

Comment: No, user552027, I won't do your homework for you.

Comment: Without preferences, Starbucks wouldn't exist. Would you like your coffee black, black, or black?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)